# jQuery toggle element if other element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**EDIT**
I don't have access to the original HTML. I can only add jQuery to the page.

I was trying to figure out how to show/hide an element (div) on a page dynamically based on if another element (div) exists.
I have a checkbox on the page that gets a class appended when clicked.

The code here is what I was thinking I would like. But it just hides the element when .is-checked exists. It doesn't toggle it back again.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
if($('.is-checked').length){
   $('.fn_container_start').hide();
}
});
```

I already have a checkbox with a class called .selectit and when you click it a class get's appended called .is-checked

I would like that when .is-checked get's appended on the page that it hides the class .fn_container_start

But also when .is-checked is not on the page, the .fn_container_start class should be hidden again.

Here's the html for the checkbox before and after it's clicked

**Before the checkbox is clicked**

```
<label class="selectit"><input value="157" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-157"> Brushes</label>
```

**After**

```
<label class="selectit is-checked"><input value="157" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-157"> Brushes</label>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Morten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use .hasClass method

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#in-download_category-157").click(function() {
    $(".selectit").toggleClass("is-checked");
        if($('.selectit').hasClass('is-checked')){
            $('.fn_container_start').hide();
        }else{
            $('.fn_container_start').show();
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: For some reason the toggle doesn't seem to remove the class again. So the div is permanently hidden.

Comment: Sorry it does remove the class, but the .fn_container_start div remains hidden

Comment: Ah yes exactly!

Comment: Would this be correct?

$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#in-download_category-157").click(function() {
    $(".selectit").toggleClass("is-checked");
    if($('.selectit').hasClass('is-checked')){
         $('.fn_container_start').hide();
      } else{$('.fn_container_start').show();        
      }
  });
});

Comment: yes correct I have updated the code as well with working condition. Please mark this as answer and upvote. thanks

Answer (score 3):

```js
function valueChanged(){
    if($('.toggle_check').is(":checked"))   {
        $('.fn_container_start').hide();
        $('.toggle_check').addClass('is-checked');
        }
    else{
        $('.fn_container_start').show();
        $('.toggle_check').removeClass('is-checked');
        }

}
```

```html
<label class="selectit"><input value="157" type="checkbox" class="toggle_check" name="download_category" id="in-download_category-157" onchange="valueChanged();"> Brushes</label>
<div class="fn_container_start">
  <p class="hide">div hides if the checkbox checked</p>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Is this possible if I don't have access to the original html. So I can only add jQuery on the page?

Comment: yeah sure.. but take care of the classes.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean take care of the classes?

Comment: i mean the reference that used to select the checkbox, here in my example i used  the class 'toggle_check' to select the checkbox and the class 'fn_container_start' is used to refer the show hide div. Hope this will make sense

Comment: the div .fn_container_start is outside the checkbox. It's just an element on the page. Will this still work?

Comment: sure dude.. will work.. and it is not possible to place div inside checkbox.

Comment: I'm not sure how to modify it though, because the html that you posted is different from mine.
I can't actually edit the html

Comment: only difference is in the additional div that i appended below the label , that is just to make u know the show hide functionality is working fine and the second difference is the onchange function.. these all are just basics and i dont know which section is confusing u thatmuch.

Comment: The problem is I can't modify the original html. So I can't add the onchange value

Comment: i have created a new snippet and hope this will helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

             $(".selectit").addClass("is-checked");

      });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.selectit').on('click', function(){
        $('.fn_container_start').toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none !important;}
.fn_container_start{border:1px dashed red;}
```

```html
<label class="selectit"><input value="157" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-157"> Brushes</label>

<div class="fn_container_start">This div have .fn_container_start class</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I'm not looking to remove a class. The checkbox already has that functionality.
I'm only looking to hide the .fn_container_start class, which is outside the checkbox

Comment: Okay added the css class to my stylesheet and tried your code.
But it doesn't seem to work. Does it need to be specified which which class to check for .is-checked? Or does it look at the entire page?

Comment: I have created a snippet check again

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.selectit input.toggle_check').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))   {
        $('.fn_container_start').hide();
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');
        }
    else{
        $('.fn_container_start').show();
        $(this).removeClass('is-checked');
        }

})
```

```html
<label class="selectit"><input value="157" type="checkbox" class="toggle_check" name="download_category" id="in-download_category-157"> Brushes</label>
<div class="fn_container_start">
  <p class="hide">div hides if the checkbox checked</p>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```